# Why does zsh completion work for VBoxManage but not vboxmanage?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I have [zsh-completions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions) installed on arch linux. Completion of `VBoxManage` command seems to work fine, but `vboxmanage` doesn't (ie. just does simple completion of files int he local directory). Both `VBoxManage` and `vboxmanage` are symlinks to the `VBox` executable.

It seems that my [_virtualbox](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/src/_virtualbox) completion definition has a first line of

```
#compdef VBoxManage=vboxmanage VBoxHeadless=vboxheadless
```

which looks like an alias of some sort? but it isn't working.

I have a fix which is to change the above line to

```
#compdef VBoxManage=vboxmanage vboxmanage=vboxmanage VBoxHeadless=vboxheadless vboxheadless=vboxheadless
```

This seems long-winded, there is an option to specify a pattern, but What is the correct way to alias commands like this?

Answer (score 1):

```sh
compdef _VBoxManage vboxmanage
compdef _VBoxHeadless vboxheadless
```

In your `~/.zshrc` is the correct way to specify a completion function for a command. It is not recommended to edit the actual function in source, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @sw1nn Do you want to accept this answer, so the question can be closed?